# Discord client sharding for multiple node k8s cluster

Tags: c#, kubernetes, sharding, multiple-instances, discord.net

I currently use DiscordSocketClient which is being handled in each pod in my k8s cluster.
I am applying manual sharding by processing the interaction command only if it's the correct pod based on a sharding formula.

However, I'd like to switch to using DiscordShardedClient instead so I don't need to do this manual sharding by myself but i could not find any example which applies sharding correctly in .NET.

This is how I implemented but it didn't work, the interactions were received by all of the DiscordShardClient instances in multiple pods:

```
//
services.AddSingleton<DiscordShardedClient>();
//
```

```
public class DiscordClientInitializer : IHostedService
{
    private readonly DiscordShardedClient _discord;

    public DiscordClientInitializer(DiscordShardedClient discord) => _discord = discord;

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _discord.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, "some_token");
        await _discord.StartAsync();
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _discord.LogoutAsync();
        await _discord.StopAsync();
    }
}
```

Is there anything else I need to set? Maybe some config?